# error in parsing JSON using GSON with retrofit API

Tags: gson, retrofit

this is POJO or model class that I am using, I'm able to get the response from server but it is throwing SyntaxException and MalformedJSONException
//Model class:

```
public class AppUser {
   public Integer userID;
   public String username;
   public String password;
   public String emailID;
   public String accessToken;

}

//JSON Retrieved:
{
  "userID": "123456",
  "username": "rkumar",
  "password": "rohitk",
  "emailID": "rohitk@gmail.com",
  "accessToken": "1weErtYo90ds8i9"
}
```

//JSON Deserializer

```
public class AppUserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<AppUser> {
    @Override
    public AppUser deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Log.d("Json element",json.toString());
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, AppUser.class);
    }
}
```

//Rest Client Constructor

```
public RestClient()
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(AppUser.class,  new AppUserDeserializer())
                .create();

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(baseURL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .build();

        signInService = restAdapter.create(SignInService.class);
    }
```

Comment: `userID` seems to be `String` not an `Integer`

Comment: I have checked for both, none is working.

Comment: respond with full stacktrace or log from retrofit as your log level is `RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL` , you must be getting details about the error.

Comment: {"userID":"1","username":"rkumar","password":"rohitk","emailID":"rohitk@chromegmail.com","accessToken":"1weErtYo90ds8i9"}
08-22 12:03:13.065  11601-11601/com.XXXX.XXXX E/Error in parsing﹕ retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2 path $

Comment: There are some java script code and comments after json in HTTP body and hence the JSON parsing failed.

Answer (score 1):

**Add `@Serializable` Annotation:**

For `Kotlin`:

```
@Serializable
data class MyDataClass(...)
```

For `Java`

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class MyDataClass implements Serializable {}
```

More details about this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77796179/14037648